# c# setup application for windows

Tags: c#

I am developing a c# application, and created setup files for that.
I installed the setup files in 32 bit machine,setup files will be install the application n c\programfiles folder. but when i run the application after installing setup files, it throws me an error as below.

```
See the end of this message for details on invoking 
just-in-time (JIT) debugging instead of this dialog box.

************** Exception Text **************
System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.
   at System.Number.StringToNumber(String str, NumberStyles options, NumberBuffer& number, NumberFormatInfo info, Boolean parseDecimal)
   at System.Number.ParseInt32(String s, NumberStyles style, NumberFormatInfo info)
   at System.Convert.ToInt32(String value)
   at TouchStation.Program.writeSettingsToRegistry()
   at TouchStation.Program.Initialize()
   at TouchStation.MainForm.statusUpdateTimer_Tick(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Timer.OnTick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Timer.TimerNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)


************** Loaded Assemblies **************
mscorlib
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.3625 (GDR.050727-3600)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v2.0.50727/mscorlib.dll
----------------------------------------
TouchStation
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.1
    Win32 Version: 2.0.0.1
    CodeBase: file:///C:/TouchStation2.0.0.1/TouchStation.exe
----------------------------------------
TouchCommonLib
    Assembly Version: 1.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 1.0.0.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/TouchStation2.0.0.1/TouchCommonLib.DLL
----------------------------------------
System
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.3624 (GDR.050727-3600)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System/2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Windows.Forms
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.3623 (GDR.050727-3600)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Windows.Forms/2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Windows.Forms.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Drawing
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.3053 (netfxsp.050727-3000)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Drawing/2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Drawing.dll
----------------------------------------
TouchServerLib
    Assembly Version: 0.9.2.0
    Win32 Version: 0.9.2.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/TouchStation2.0.0.1/TouchServerLib.DLL
----------------------------------------
System.Configuration
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.3053 (netfxsp.050727-3000)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Configuration/2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Configuration.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Xml
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.3082 (QFE.050727-3000)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Xml/2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Xml.dll
----------------------------------------
WindowsHookLib
    Assembly Version: 1.1.1.0
    Win32 Version: 1.0.0.4
    CodeBase: file:///C:/TouchStation2.0.0.1/WindowsHookLib.DLL
----------------------------------------
Accessibility
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.3053 (netfxsp.050727-3000)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/assembly/GAC_MSIL/Accessibility/2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/Accessibility.dll
----------------------------------------
ThingzDB
    Assembly Version: 1.3.1.0
    Win32 Version: 1.3.1.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/TouchStation2.0.0.1/ThingzDB.DLL
----------------------------------------
System.Data.SQLite
    Assembly Version: 1.0.65.0
    Win32 Version: 1.0.65.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/TouchStation2.0.0.1/System.Data.SQLite.DLL
----------------------------------------
System.Data
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.3053 (netfxsp.050727-3000)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/assembly/GAC_32/System.Data/2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Data.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Transactions
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.3053 (netfxsp.050727-3000)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/assembly/GAC_32/System.Transactions/2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Transactions.dll
----------------------------------------
HttpServer.MVC
    Assembly Version: 1.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 1.0.0.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/TouchStation2.0.0.1/HttpServer.MVC.DLL
----------------------------------------
HttpServer
    Assembly Version: 1.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 1.0.0.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/TouchStation2.0.0.1/HttpServer.DLL
----------------------------------------
System.EnterpriseServices
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.3053 (netfxsp.050727-3000)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/assembly/GAC_32/System.EnterpriseServices/2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.EnterpriseServices.dll
----------------------------------------

************** JIT Debugging **************
To enable just-in-time (JIT) debugging, the .config file for this
application or computer (machine.config) must have the
jitDebugging value set in the system.windows.forms section.
The application must also be compiled with debugging
enabled.

For example:

<configuration>
    <system.windows.forms jitDebugging="true" />
</configuration>

When JIT debugging is enabled, any unhandled exception
will be sent to the JIT debugger registered on the computer
rather than be handled by this dialog box.
```

But when i place this application in other drives like e drive then the application runs with out any problem.

Please let me know if any fix.

Regards
sangita

Comment: Try to debug params passed to `System.Number.StringToNumber` function, maybe writing them to a text file you can show us please...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to convert a string to a number in this method: at TouchStation.Program.writeSettingsToRegistry() - without that code we can't really help further however.

Comment: It seems like that, but OP is telling us that if the same software is run from a different location on the same pc (drive E) everything works... it sounds strange, but I'm waiting some other info...

Comment: The author of the question is wrong.  It might work on some inputs on another machine but the exception is clear, this has nothing to do with x86 or x64 operating systems.

Comment: @Ramhound: well, an instant after reading the error I thought it could be something about locale (decimal separator for example) but OP is saying that on the same pc but different location everythink works. Probably he's wrong, you're right, but without any other info we can do nothing, right? ;)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in regional setting's.
For example seperator for decimals is "," instead of "."